# Conditional Formatting in Excel (Formula)

Tags: excel, formula

how would I go about making a conditional formatting formula that indicates if a cell has ANY value it will highlight the row green? its hard to put in words but hopefully this makes sense

Comment: So test for not blank:  C1<>""

Comment: What @SolarMike Sir, has mentioned is absolutely correct, using `ISBLANK` function wont give you proper output!